# List all available sources packages that doesn't have a binay packages

Tags: debian, packaging

I need to get the list of sources packages that doesn't have a binary packages on Debian.

Listing all sources packages may be an answer, so we can get the `diff` between the available binary and the available sources package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I’m aware, all source packages in Debian must produce at least one binary package on at least one architecture.

To count the number of binary packages produced by the source packages available in the system’s configured source repositories (`deb-src` lines), run

```
awk '/Package:/{p=$2;b=0} /Binary:/{b=NF - 1} /^$/{printf "%s: %d\n", p, b} END{printf "%s: %d\n", p, b}' /var/lib/apt/lists/*Sources
```

This fails to find any source package with no binary packages in the current stable, testing, unstable and experimental repositories.

If you want to determine which source packages don’t produce any binaries on a given architecture, you can proceed as follows:

- list the unique source package names globally:

  ```
  awk '/Package:/{print $2}' /var/lib/apt/lists/*_Sources | sort -u > source-packages
  ```
- list the source packages used to produce a given architecture’s binaries (excluding `all`, which is included in the arch-specific indexes):

  ```
  awk '/(Package|Source):/{source=$2}/Version:/{print source}' /var/lib/apt/lists/*-amd64_Packages | sort -u > amd64-packages
  ```
- list entries present in the list of global source packages but not in those used for `amd64`:

  ```
  comm -23 source-packages amd64-packages
  ```